# Windows Server with RAID error message after power outage - not booting

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, boot, electrical-power

Good afternoon,

We had a power outage last week at one of our remote sites which brought down the entire server room. Most of the systems came back online after the outage was resolved, but we have one that is being stubborn. After power cycling the server and reseating all the connections multiple times, I was finally able to access it via KVM. Now, however, we are getting the following error:

[RAID fault message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPass.jpg)

I followed some other advice - powering the system off, unplugging everything, and leaving it off for ~10 minutes - but that did not solve the issue.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you run the PERC configuration utility and looked at the disks and array?

Answer (score 0):

If you press 'c' to configure, you should be able to see which disks are missing. Considering it was a power outage, you should be prepared for the worst-case scenario, that several drives have died. You will likely need to add new drives, re-build your array and restore from a backup.